# Ensure transition completes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following pie chart with a very nice transition:

http://plnkr.co/edit/b4uLimUSZzxiPzAkNpBt?p=preview

The code for the pie chart is the following:

```
function addPieChart(meas, dataFile) {

    var width = 400,
        height = 400,
        radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2.1,
        color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range(["#016da9", "#4c96d5"])
        .domain([0, 1]);


    //check if the svg already exists
    var plot = d3.select("#svgPIEChart")
    if (plot.empty()) {
        var vis = d3.select("#pieChart")
            .append("svg") //create the SVG element 
            .attr({
                id: "svgPIEChart"
            })
    } else {
        var vis = d3.select("#svgPIEChart")
        vis.selectAll("*").remove();
    };

    //svg element
    vis.attr({
        //set the width and height of our visualization (these will be attributes of the <svg> tag
        width: width,
        height: height
    });

    //group of the svg element
    var svg = vis
        .append("g")
        .attr({
            'transform': "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height * .52 + ")"
        });


    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .startAngle(function(d) {
            return d.x;
        })
        .endAngle(function(d) {
            return d.x + d.dx;
        })
        .outerRadius(function(d) {
            return (d.y + d.dy) / (radius);
        })
        .innerRadius(function(d) {
            return d.y / (radius);
        });


    d3.text(dataFile, function(text) {
        var csv = d3.csv.parseRows(text);
        var json = buildHierarchy(csv);



        // it seems d3.layout.partition() can be either squares or arcs
        var partition = d3.layout.partition()
            .sort(null)
            .size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius])
            .value(function(d) {
                return d.Revenue;
            });

        var path = svg.data([json]).selectAll(".theArc")
            .data(partition.nodes)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "theArc") //<<<<<<<<<<new jq
            .attr("id", function(d, i) {
                return "theArc_" + i;
            }) //Give each slice a unique ID //<<<<<<<<<<new jq
            .attr("display", function(d) {
                return d.depth ? null : "none";
            })
            .attr("d", arc)
            .style("stroke", "#fff")
            .style("fill", function(d) {
                return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name);
            })
            .attr("fill-rule", "evenodd")
            .style("opacity", 1)
            .on("mouseover", mouseover) 
            .on("mouseout", mouseout) 
            .on("click", up)
            .each(stash);

        // path.each(stash).on("click", up) 

        //this is a start>>>>>   
        path
            .append("title") //mouseover title showing the figures
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.name + ": " + formatAsShortInteger(d.Revenue);
            });

        //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
        svg.data([json]).selectAll(".theTxts")
            .data(partition.nodes)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr("class", "theTxts")
            .attr("dx", 10) //Move the text from the start angle of the arc
            .attr("dy", 15) //Move the text down
            .append("textPath")
            .attr("class", "foo")
            .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) {
                return "#theArc_" + i;
            })
            .text(function(d) {
                if ((d.name != 'root') && ((d.name != 'B T') || (currentMeasure != 'W'))) {
                    return d.name;
                }
            })
            .on("click", up) //<<<new jq;

        svg.append("text")
            .attr({
                x: "0",
                y: "0",
                'class': "title",
                "id": "titleX",
                'text-anchor': "middle"
            })
            .text(currentMeasure + " split")
            //>>
            .append("tspan")
            .attr({
                dy: "1.1em",
                x: 0,
                'text-anchor': "middle"
            })
            .text("for " + latestMth)
            .attr("class", "title");



        d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function change() {

            value = createValueFunc(this.value);
            currentMeasure = this.value;

            var path2 = svg.data([json]).selectAll(".theArc");
            path2
                .data(partition.value(value).nodes)
                .transition()
                .duration(1500)
                .attrTween("d", arcTween)


            //to update the tooltips  
            svg.selectAll("title")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.name + ": " + formatAsShortInteger(value(d));
                });


            svg.selectAll("textPath")
                .text(function(d) {
                    if ((d.name != 'root') && ((d.name != 'B T') || (currentMeasure != 'W'))) {
                        return d.name;
                    }
                });

            // the following deletes what was originally created and then recreates the text
            svg.selectAll("#titleX").remove();
            svg.append("text")
                .attr({
                    x: "0",
                    y: "0",
                    'class': "title",
                    "id": "titleX",
                    'text-anchor': "middle"
                })
                .text(currentMeasure + " split")
                .append("tspan")
                .attr({
                    dy: "1.1em",
                    x: 0,
                    'text-anchor': "middle"
                })
                .text("for " + latestMth)
                .attr("class", "title");


            addProdTitl();
            updateTOPbarChart(currentGrp, currentMeasure, currentColr);
            updateBOTbarChart(currentGrp, currentMeasure, currentColr);

        });



        function mouseover() {
            d3.select(this)
                .transition()
                .duration(200)
                .style("opacity", 0.9);
        };

        function mouseout() {
            d3.select(this)
                .transition()
                .duration(200)
                .style("opacity", 1);
        };


        // update bar chart when user selects piece of the pie chart
        function up(d, i) {

            currentGrp = d.name;

            // (d.children ? d : d.parent).name
            currentColr = color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); // color(d.name);

            addProdTitl();
            updateTOPbarChart(d.name, currentMeasure, currentColr); //color(d.name));
            updateBOTbarChart(d.name, currentMeasure, currentColr); //color(d.name));

        };


        // Stash the old values for transition.
        function stash(d) {
            d.x0 = d.x;
            d.dx0 = d.dx;
        };

        // Interpolate the arcs in data space.
        function arcTween(a) {
            var i = d3.interpolate({
                x: a.x0,
                dx: a.dx0
            }, a);
            return function(t) {
                var b = i(t);
                a.x0 = b.x;
                a.dx0 = b.dx;
                return arc(b);
            };
        };


    });


};
```

If you change the selection of the radio button and then click on a section of the pie chart that section does not complete its transition as I believe it decides it needs to move on to its "on" event.

How do I ensure that the transition completes? (and the pie chart does not do a pac-man impersonation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Clear your listeners when the tranistion starts.
2. Attach it when the transition is ended

Like this:

```
 path2
                    .data(partition.value(value).nodes)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(1500)
                    .attrTween("d", arcTween)
                    .each("start", function(){
                      d3.select(this)
                      .on("mouseover", null) //CLEARING the listeners
                      .on("mouseout", null) //CLEARING the listeners
                      .on("click", null) //CLEARING the listeners
                    })
                    .each("end", function(){
                      d3.select(this)
                      .on("mouseover", mouseover) //attaching the listeners
                      .on("mouseout", mouseout) //attaching the listeners
                      .on("click", up) ////attaching the listeners
                    });
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fv3n9CX2Yn1lknhiDGr4?p=preview)

Comment: (upped) this is excellent. One tiny bit of functionality that is now lost is that when I hover over a slice, when the visual is initially rendered, the opacity does not transition to indicate that the cursor is hovering over it. After this event `selectAll("input").on("change",` has happened this functionality returns i.e. once the user has hit the radio button. Can I add a line of code somewhere so when the visual is initially rendered a change event to the radio buttons is triggered to ensure that the opacity transition is in place from the off ?

Comment: Yeah missed that part. I have edited my answer accordingly. You will need to attach the listeners initially(as you were doing before). Then later on change of radio value, detach the listener as transition is started, post transition attach listeners back.

Comment: cool - did you need to force a change of radio value in the code when the visual is first rendered - or was it just necessary to add back my listeners ? (... reason I ask is that there are quite a few lines of code so just checking in case you added any lines of code, that I might nmot have spotted, other than those specified in your snippet of code above)

Comment: I added back your listeners that's all. I did not force a change in the radio value.